# Get error array from selenium get_log function

Tags: robotframework

I want to extract the array error from Chrome console.

I have a RIDE application with an OpenBrowserAndLog function, that it should open the browser in logging mode, as follows:

```
${c_opts}=  Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()   sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method ${c_opts}   add_argument    enable-logging
Call Method ${c_opts}   add_argument    v\=1
Call Method ${c_opts}   add_argument    loglevel\=ERROR
Create Webdriver    Chrome  crm_alias   chrome_options=${c_opts}
```

Then, I have a python script that extracts those logs, using the selenium library and webdriver:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def get_log():
    selib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
    f = open('get_log_result.txt', 'a')
    str1 = ', '.join(map(str,selib.driver.get_log('browser')))
    f.write(str1)
    f.close()
    return True
```

my output is:

```
'source': 'network', 'timestamp': 1563272856199}, {'level': 'SEVERE', 'message': 'https://10.158.114.251:3080/hijat2-ui-static/main.4380998255cb0e09727f.js 0:908345 "ERROR" Array(10)', 'source': 'console-api', 'timestamp': 1563272876919}
```

What i want to get are the 10 ERRORs inside that "ERROR" Array